# Issue creating exec with pynsist and nsis

Tags: python, pip, nsis, openpyxl

I am using pynsist and nsis to develop my python app.
However the exec produced by nsis appears to be quite faulty:

```
File "C:\Path\pkgs\openpyxl\utils\datetime.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jdcal import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jdcal'
```

Meanwhile when I attemt to install jdcal with 
`C:\Path>pip install jdcal` 
I receive this message

```
Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in c:\Path\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
```

From what I understand, jdcal is installed through openpyxl and openpyxl is installed correctly, so what is the problem?

Comment: openpyxl only supports installation via `pip`

Comment: You have not posted any NSIS code so why even include the tag?